# How to upload a file to a remote server using python

Tags: python, wsgi

I need to upload a file to a remote location using python - wsgi.
Remote location means not the server which host the python application, it is a different server.

I tried upload a file to the server which exactly the application host. And it is succeeded.

using following code,

```
            post = cgi.FieldStorage(fp=environ['wsgi.input'],environ=environ,keep_blank_values=True)
        self.msg = str(post)            

        try:
            fileitem = post['Filedata']
            if fileitem.file:
                filename = fileitem.filename.decode('utf8').replace('\\','/').split('/')[-1].strip()
                if not filename:
                    raise Exception('No valid filename specified')
                file_path = os.path.join(self.uploadpath, filename)
                # Using with makes Python automatically close the file for you
                counter = 0
                with open(file_path, 'wb') as output_file:
                    while 1:
                        data = fileitem.file.read(1024)
                        # End of file
                        if not data:
                            break
                        output_file.write(data)
                        counter += 1
                        if counter == 100:
                            counter = 0
            self.msg = "Uploaded Successfully !!!! "
        except:
            pass
```

But this is for the the local location which the python application hosted.
I search about Google how to upload a file to remote location in python. 
But I can't find a proper solution for that. Some are suggested to do scp from python code.

more..

Let say there are two servers called A and B. My python-wsgi application for file uploading is hosted on server A. In the python-wsgi application there is a web form to select the file by user when user click upload then that file need to uploaded to server B (known location)

Any one knows a way or library to upload a file to remote location using python?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what are you asking about ? I need to upload a file to a remote location using python.

Comment: SO is for answering specific questions; you haven't asked a question, just stated that you need to do something.  i'm not going to write your code for you.  if you've made an _attempt_ and it doesn't work, then by all means maybe we can help you out with that.

Comment: What kind of server is it? HTTP? FTP? Do you have root privileges there? Can you install needed services / servers / whatever? Do you want to put another Python script there?

Comment: Its and HTTP server. Yes have root privileges. No I don't want to put another python scripts and also is there a way without installing any services to the target server. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For HTTP, you won't have any chance to put a file on the server without an adequate counterpart on the server-side, i.e., a Python / Perl / PHP / Ruby / whatever script that takes the data you provide in a **HTTP POST** - request and writes them to a file. I'd recommend setting up an FTP-server. That's exactly what FTP was invented for.

Usually, most HTTP servers have FTP as well. How do you put your HTML-files on the server? FTP is kind-of minimal access needed to do so. It's really not hard to set up.

Comment: Thanks for this. I think this will solve my problem. I found  ftplib in python for FTP.

Comment: That's exactly the way to go. Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

File uploads are usually implemented as a HTTP POST operation using *enctype=multipart/form-data*.

See

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_enctype.asp

In Python you can use the **requests** module for convenience.

Aside from that: you question is poor.

Comment: Many thanks for responding. But I need to upload to a remote location not to the server it self where the application is hosted.

Comment: What you are asking makes zero sense without further feedback. Take your time and ask something making sense to us (or let it be).

Comment: Let say there are two servers called A and B. My python application for file uploading is hosted on server A. In the python-wsgi application there is a web form to select the file by user  when user click upload then that file need to uploaded to server B (known location).

Comment: You have basically no idea what you are asking.